# bash script to select a disk for dd (lsblk?)

Tags: bash, dd, disk

I'm trying to make a script to select into which disk I should dd to.

A simple bash script to select options works like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

`lsblk` is the best way I know to read disks:

```
lz@vm:~/Downloads$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop1    7:1    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop2    7:2    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop3    7:3    0 138,5M  1 loop /snap/inkscape/8049
loop4    7:4    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop5    7:5    0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop6    7:6    0  31,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
loop7    7:7    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
sda      8:0    1  14,9G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1  14,9G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
vda    252:0    0   300G  0 disk 
├─vda1 252:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─vda2 252:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─vda5 252:5    0 299,5G  0 part /
```

You can see that `df -h` does not list `/dev/sda` on my machine:

```
lz@vm:~/Downloads$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4,5G     0  4,5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           924M  1,6M  922M   1% /run
/dev/vda5       294G   62G  218G  23% /
tmpfs           4,6G   26M  4,5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4,6G     0  4,6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop5      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop2       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop4       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop1      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop7       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/loop3      139M  139M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/8049
/dev/loop6       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/vda1       511M  4,0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           924M   60K  924M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/fuse       250G     0  250G   0% /run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs
```

I don't know why.

Anyways, what would be the best way to list these disks (not the partitions like `/dev/sda1`, just the disk) so I can create a list of options to select one and `dd` to it? Is there a way to format these with lsbk so I can insert into my bash script?

Aditionally, it would be nice to ignore the disk where the script lies on, so I can try to prevent writing to the disk that contains the system.

Comment: `df` only lists mounted devices. `sda` or partitions thereof have no mountpoints as you can see in the `lsblk` output.

Comment: But `df` can be used to get the current device you're on: `df $(pwd)`  or within the script `df $0`. This may be used for the "ignore own device" part. Be careful though if you e.g. have a separated partition for `/home` you may still kill your root FS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `lsblk -d`

> `-d, --nodeps` Don't print device holders or slaves. (...)

How could I parse the table generated by this command?
`lsblk -d | tail -n+2 | cut -d" " -f1`

Would be good if I had a way to collect a name and the size so I can put in the option

`lsblk -d | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1" "$4}'`

Should I assume it's simply /dev/NAME?

Yes, that is the location for devices. You can use `test -b` to check it.

> `-b FILE`
> FILE exists and is block special

```
if [ -b /dev/vda ]; then
  echo "is a block device"
fi
```

if you check your devices with `ls -l /dev/vda` it should start with a `b`
**b**rw-rw---- 1 root disk (...) /dev/vda

In the end `lsblk` is listing block devices - no need to double check.

Comment: How could I parse the table generated by this command? Would be good if I had a way to collect a name and the size so I can put in the option

Comment: answered the questions in my post

Comment: is there a way to display their paths? It's not possible to dd if I don't know the path. Or should I assume it's simply /dev/NAME?

Comment: answered the question in my post